# How to detect virtual threads on java 19

Tags: java, reflection, module-info, project-loom, virtual-threads

Lets say I want to ship a program that runs on java 17 as that is what is available widely, but use reflection to detect if im running on a vm with the ability to produce a thread factory via `Thread.ofVirtual().name("abc").factory()`. Java prohibits reflective access to its internals when they are not properly configured with modules. How do I configure my program to be able to access this method reflectively? The reason for reflective access is to continue compiling into <jdk19 bytecode, but use reflection to use jdk19 features if they are present. Is there a combination of arguments or `module-info.java` contents that can achieve this goal, or is this not possible?

when you try this in jshell, here is what you get:

```
jshell --enable-preview
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 19.0.2
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> Thread.class.getMethod("ofVirtual")
   ...>                 .invoke(null)
   ...>                 .getClass()
   ...>                 .getMethod("name", String.class, Long.TYPE)
   ...>                 .setAccessible(true)
|  Exception java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public java.lang.Thread$Builder$OfVirtual java.lang.ThreadBuilders$VirtualThreadBuilder.name(java.lang.String,long) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @30dae81
|        at AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException (AccessibleObject.java:387)
|        at AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible (AccessibleObject.java:363)
|        at AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible (AccessibleObject.java:311)
|        at Method.checkCanSetAccessible (Method.java:201)
|        at Method.setAccessible (Method.java:195)
|        at (#1:5)
```

> Exception java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public java.lang.Thread$Builder$OfVirtual java.lang.ThreadBuilders$VirtualThreadBuilder.name(java.lang.String,long) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @30dae81

adding `required java.base;` into the `module-info.java` does not seem to change the outcome either:

```java
// src/main/java/module-info.java
module test_20230518_ {
    requires java.base;
}
```

```java
// src/main/java/a/A.java

package a;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadFactory threadFactory = tf();
        threadFactory.newThread(() ->
                System.out.println("hi from " +
                        Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }

    private static ThreadFactory tf() {
        Method[] methods = Thread.class.getMethods();
        boolean haveVirtual = Arrays.stream(methods)
                .anyMatch(m -> m.getName().equals("ofVirtual") &&
                        m.getParameterCount() == 0);

        if (haveVirtual) {
            try {
                Object b = Thread.class.getMethod("ofVirtual")
                        .invoke(null);
                b = b.getClass().getMethod("name", String.class, Long.TYPE)
                        .invoke(b, "prefix-", (long) 1);
                b = b.getClass().getMethod("factory")
                        .invoke(b);
                return (ThreadFactory) b;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new RuntimeException(t);
            }
        } else {
            return Thread::new;
        }
    }
}
```

still produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class a.A cannot access a member of class java.lang.ThreadBuilders$VirtualThreadBuilder (in module java.base) with modifiers "public volatile"
    at a.A.tf(A.java:31)
    at a.A.main(A.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class a.A cannot access a member of class java.lang.ThreadBuilders$VirtualThreadBuilder (in module java.base) with modifiers "public volatile"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:420)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:709)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at a.A.tf(A.java:26)
    ... 1 more
```

> class a.A cannot access a member of class java.lang.ThreadBuilders$VirtualThreadBuilder (in module java.base) with modifiers "public volatile"

Comment: Consider creating a multi-release JAR instead, with specific code for Java 19, and alternative code for Java 17. Though to be honest, I'm not sure that will work, because virtual threads are a preview feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Expression class from java.beans package (from java.desktop module)

```
 import java.beans.Expression;
 var builder = new Expression(Thread.class, "ofVirtual", null).getValue();
 builder = new Expression(builder, "name", new Object[] {"ABC"}).getValue();
 var factory = new Expression(builder, "factory", null).getValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [use `Expression` from the `java.beans` package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75791015/2711488) if you don’t mind creating a dependency to the `java.desktop` module, but it’s worth highlighting what it does different than your approach.

You issue is not specific to the module system, but a widespread wrong use of the Reflection API. When you use `getClass()`, you get the actual (implementation) class of an object and it’s possible that this class is not `public` and hence, the methods you get with `getClass().getMethod(…)` are inaccessible despite overriding or implementing a `public`, accessible API.

Instead of trying to hotfix this by calling `setAccessible(true)` on the method, you should try to navigate to the right API class, either via `getSuperclass()` or `getInterfaces()`. In this specific case, we want the [`Thread.Builder.OfVirtual` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.Builder.OfVirtual.html) which matches the declared return type of [`Thread.ofVirtual()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#ofVirtual()):

```java
private static ThreadFactory tf() {
    Optional<Method> virtual = Arrays.stream(Thread.class.getMethods())
        .filter(m -> m.getParameterCount() == 0 && m.getName().equals("ofVirtual"))
        .findAny();

    if(virtual.isPresent()) {
        try {
            Method method = virtual.orElseThrow();
            Object b = method.invoke(null);
         // matches b.getClass().getInterfaces()[0]
         //   but method.getReturnType() is more reliable
            Class<?> factoryClass = method.getReturnType();
            b = factoryClass.getMethod("name", String.class, long.class)
                .invoke(b, "prefix-", 1L);
            return (ThreadFactory)factoryClass.getMethod("factory").invoke(b);
        }
        catch(ReflectiveOperationException t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }
    else {
        return Thread::new;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `virtual.orElseThrow().getReturnType()`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn good point. Incorporated.

Comment: Generally, in the java language every expression has a type, which is used to find the method to invoke. So, if you want to do `foo.bar().baz()` reflectively, always use the declared return type of `bar` when trying to find the `baz` method. That will save you a lot of headaches. (Many expression languages ignore that and either use `getClass()` on the target or try to reconstruct a possible target type by walking the type hierarchy.)